# how to change the contents of TextView in realtime

Tags: android, textview, real-time

the UI is very simple, only having a button `login` and a scrollable TextView on it, when i press the button `login`, 100 lines of messages will add to the TextView, but they are added at the same time, and because i need do with the messages that will add to the TextView, which will cost a few time, sometimes the app looks like no response. i hope that the message could add to the TextView line by line. IOW i want the TextView displays the added line of message in each loop. how can i realize that? Here is the main code which has been simplified:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            mTextView.append("test\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
       mTextView.setText(""); 
       for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText()+"test\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Try this code it should work

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {

       mTextView.setText(""); 
if (!isStopped) { 

       Acitivut.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
        @Override  
        public void run() {   
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          mTextView.append("test\n");
         }
isStopped=true; 
        }  
        });  
}
      }
    }
```

Comment: thx, but where should i define the variable isStopped? i tried to add the line `boolean isStopped = false` before `if(!isStopped) {`, but `isStopped` cannot be inspected in `new Runnable(){}` because its in another class.

Comment: if working fine then leave it.i have added this variable bez if user click two time at same time on button then prevent it.

Comment: @MarkZar : please make your on logic for this conditon

Answer (score 0):

Anything that changes UI element, must run on UI thread. Since you are running long running loop, your app freezes. You should either change the design and avoid updating UI in loop or you can use run a `background thread` and append the text to `StringBuilder` and when loop is over, append the StringBuilder text to the mtextView.

Again, if your StringBuilder contains very large text, updating that to UI may freeze it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
           i=0; 
           Thread thread=new Thread(new SleepThread());
           thread.start();
    }
}

private class SleepThread implements Runnable
{
         public void run()
         {
              sleep(10);
              handler.sendEmptyMessage();
         }
}

Handler handler=new Handler()
{
     public void handleMessage(Message msg)
     {
         mTextView.append("test\n");
         i++;
         if(i<100)
         {
              Thread thread=new Thread(new SleepThread());
              thread.start();
         }
     }
}
```